# add to cart message in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

As mentioned above I want to display "product added to cart message" in woocommerce.

I know there is some kind of built in function

```
wc_add_to_cart_message()
```

If I paste it in index page together with

```
wc_print_notices();
```

Like this:

```
wc_add_to_cart_message('products');
wc_print_notices();
```

then my current output is:

```
“” has been added to your cart.
```

My desired output is:

```
 that it would return that particular product name together with a message.
```

but what would be the proper way of using it?

Or is there some other way?

Comment: You can use `wc_add_to_cart_message` hook and in that callback function you can return product id or anything you want

Comment: If I use it like this:
wc_add_to_cart_message($product) it returns "Page title added to cart"
But I need product name to be displayed - not page title

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Default message is "product name" has been added to cart. Isn't it what you need ? Are you creating custom function ?

Comment: Nope...it doesnt return product name. That is the problem. Lets say the page title is called "Special products".
It returns "Special products added to cart".
I have to pass and ID of a product in wc_add_to_cart_message(productID) But how this function should be used?

Comment: Are you using any hooks in your functions.php like `wc_add_to_cart_message_html` ?

Comment: no. I was using in my template file `<?php wc_add_to_cart_message($product)
wc_print_notices();
?>`
And that it